# Xul Scrollbox button disappearing

Tags: scrollbar, xul, xulrunner

If you run this simple Xul example, you can see that when you scroll from the last (3°) button to the first, using tab, the middle button disappear. Any idea why? And how to fix?

*(to run it you'll need to put an png image named "img.png" at content folder)*

**test.xul**

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://test/content/test.css" type="text/css"?>

<window id="desktop" title="test" width="1280" height="720" xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul">

    <scrollbox>
        <button image="chrome://test/content/img.png" />
        <button image="chrome://test/content/img.png" />
        <button image="chrome://test/content/img.png" />
    </scrollbox>

</window>
```

**test.css**

```
#desktop {
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:transparent;
    border-width:50px;
}

button {
    position: absolute;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background: url(""); /* nothing */
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    z-index: 1;
}

button image {
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
}

button:focus image {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
}

scrollbox {
    background-color: #555555;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved inserting the scrollbox inside a box, and setting the scroll's background color to the box.